# Android "extends ListActivity" error, unable to instantiate activity componentinfo

Tags: android, android-activity, instantiation, listactivity

Hello guys this is my first question here, and yes I saw a lot of questions and answears like these and tried all the ways but I always get ~unable to instantiate activity componentinfo~ here I'll give my code, I'm just trying to make a simple list of Strings.

Here we come!

That's my class:

```
@package br.com.volkmann.volkmannbus;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class ConsultaActivity extends ListActivity {

String[] lista = {
        "12:30",
        "13:00"
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_consulta);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lista));

}

}
```

And this one my XML, Activity:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#f8f18b" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listaHora"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Every time I start the activity there comes the error!

And this is the class that creates the Intent:

```
package br.com.volkmann.volkmannbus;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;

public class HorarioActivity extends Activity {

private Button btConsulta;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_horario);      

    btConsulta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btConsulta);
    btConsulta.setOnClickListener(cliqueConsulta);
    }
      View.OnClickListener cliqueConsulta = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(HorarioActivity.this, ConsultaActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
 }
```

That's the most especific I got!
Sorry for bad english, I'm a Brazilian!

Comment: post the manifest and the logact

Comment: read this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listaHora"
```

to

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
```

example code here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Comment: maaan thanks a lot, issue solved, and thanks for the link, I started programing yesterday with my nexus 4 that that I bought, keep the good work!

Answer (score 1):

With `ListActivity` your layout must contain a `ListView` with id `@android:id/list` but you have `@+id/listaHora`.

Other than that, have a look at the exception stacktrace in logcat, especially the "caused by" exception. Also when having such problems, include the full stacktrace in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should change to

```
 <ListView android:id="@android:id/list
```

Read this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

In your case you get rid of  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_consulta);` as you have no other view's in your xml.

The ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen